# Can't access hidden service after hostname switch

Tags: network-configuration

I made my own hidden service using this guide: https://medium.com/@ajphillips/how-to-create-your-own-tor-hidden-service-436bece8602f

Everything worked fine using the generated hostname I received during the process, now I made my own .onion link using mkp224o and I replaced the original hostname + key files with the ones I received from mkp224o however now when I try to connect to my .onion link (the new one) it says it cannot find the server.

Comment: What does your tor log say? Assuming you're running the debian systemd service, run `sudo journalctl -u tor@default` and paste any important logs into your question.

Comment: https://paste.centos.org/view/fa723ad3
I didn't change anything in the configuraitons, only replaced the hostname & keys

Comment: ended up being isseus with the systems permission and mpk224o not auto setting them.